# Pass an array inside foreach into a variable outside the foreach?

Tags: php

Im taking data from a form and e-mailing it using `wp_mail`, since there is multiple data (all check box data) there obviously needs to be a foreach.

I cannot wrap my head around getting the data inside the foreach and using it outside the statement.

```
 //My form data
 $checks = $_POST['personalization_result'];

 //Pass the foreach array into this variable and use this to mail
 $checkString = '';

    //For each checkbox data
    foreach ($checks as $k => $v) {
     var_dump ($v);
    }

 //Email the data
 $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, $checkString, $headers); //I have set up the other variables but its not necessary to add here just focused on $checkString
```

Snippet of the form

```
<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post"> 

<?php echo $checkString; ?>// Trying to see what the array is doing

<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">

<p><input type="submit"></p>

<li class="option table selected">
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="personalization_result[memory_0]">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="personalization_result[memory_0]" id="personalization_result_memory_0" checked="checked">                                        
</li> 


<li class="option table selected">
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="personalization_result[memory_1]">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="personalization_result[memory_1]" id="personalization_result_memory_1" checked="checked">                                    
</li>
```

Im sorry if this is a bit noobish, but this is how I learn by asking.

Comment: Declare the array outside the for.

Comment: Are you saying you want to append `$v` to `$checkString` each loop?

Comment: Instead of `var_dump($v)` do `$checkString .= $v;`. The `.=` means append to string.

Comment: Yeah, its straightforward what I am trying to do, just email all the form values whether its 1(checked) or 0(not checked)

Comment: oh ok, then I can use $checkString outside the foreach? let me give it a crack

Comment: Please include that sentence in your question next time :) Lots of newcomers are doing things in a way that is not best or not even close to whatever they wish to do. So we (at least me) cannot be sure that whatever seems to happen in the code is the purpose of the writer.

Comment: @AmazingDreams  yeah that looks like it works, I echoed it and it returned each check value whether it is 1 or 0

Comment: Please see the answer below for a cleaner way to do it ;)

Comment: @AmazingDreams yeah I understand, its tough to articulate it precisely, next time Ill make sure to add a sentance that is more accurate towards what I am trying to accomplish but thats what makes this little discussion so wonderful. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `wp_mail`'s third parameter `message` is a string, I think you can avoid the foreach altogether and use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to get values as an array and join them with some glue  instead of looping through the `$checks` array.  Please try:

```
$checkValues = array_values($checks);
$checkString = implode(',', $checkValues); // This generates comma separated list of values.
```

You could use any glue (comma in this example) you like in the [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function call based on how you want to display the `.$checkValues`

Comment: Thanks, im going to implement this now!

Comment: YES this worked nicely, youre the man... the answers above were good as well, but I like this :) Just emailed myself and it worked wonderfully..